# How to test a non-payable function which doesn't return anything in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing

Inside my smart contract I'm having this function:

```
function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
```

I want to `write a test` in hardhat to get my coverage 100%.

`people[]` array and `nameToFavoriteNumber` mapping are public.

```
 uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;
```

How can I achieve this without making any changes in smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

With hardhat, deploy your contract, then check that people[] is emply (i.e. people[0].name == '' or something like that), then call the addPerson() function, then checks that people[] is not empty anymore (i.e. people[0].name == 'Tusher Bharti').